# AntD table customised filter functionality is not working with react version 15.4.2

Tags: reactjs, antd

We are using Antd table in our application which is build with react version 15.4.2.We are trying to implement 'customised filter panel' https://codesandbox.io/s/q326o1jywj which is not working with version 15.4.2.Also for other features(Filter and sorter) we are not able to get the icons.
Is there any workaround for this issue, Can we implement these features with some configuration changes in react  15.4.2 version ? Please help us

Comment: I visited the sandbox and your code seems to be working can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: No, the link I shared is the example given for search feature from Antd table page.I have shared it for reference.
In that sandbox if we change the react version from latest to 15.4.2, then page is breaking

Comment: change both react and react dom to 15.4.2 and everything seems to be working as expected